# How to get span text in in php variable?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

```
<span class="cid"></span>
```

In the above span, i am getting id from .js file. eg., 45 and i want that id in php variable. eg., $cid='45';

I have already tried below code, but i am unable to get id.

```
<?php echo $cid='<span class="cid"></span>'; ?>

<?php
    $str = $cid;

    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    $DOM->loadHTML($str);

    $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('span');
    $span_list = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
        $item = $items->item($i);
        $span_list[$item->getAttribute('class')] = $item->nodeValue;
    }
    extract($span_list);

    echo $cid; 
?>
```

Comment: Do you want to get the value of class of the span tag using the PHP?

Comment: yes BhavinThummar

Comment: you can check my code in answer.

Answer (score 2):

try this one add span text in php code to get the span value in variable

```html
<?php
$value = '<span class="cid"></span>';
?>
echo $value
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try the below code and check at your end you can get class value in the array.

> Second time Update code

```
    <?php 
    echo $cid='<span class="cid">45</span>'; 
?>

<?php
    $str = $cid;

    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    $DOM->loadHTML($str);

    $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('span');
    $span_list = '';

    for($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
        $item = $items->item($i);

        if($item->getAttribute('class') == 'cid'){
            $span_list = $item->nodeValue;
        }
    }

    echo $span_list;
?>
```

> Code for multiple span tags and get single value from that span list array.

```
    <?php 
    $cid='<span class="cid">45</span> <span class="cid">48</span>'; 
?>

<?php
    $str = $cid;

    $DOM = new DOMDocument;
    $DOM->loadHTML($str);

    $items = $DOM->getElementsByTagName('span');
    $span_list = array();

    for($i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++) {
        $item = $items->item($i);

        if($item->getAttribute('class') == 'cid'){
            $span_list[] = $item->nodeValue;
        }
    }

    //get the each value for multiple span tag

    foreach ($span_list as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
        echo '<br/>';       
    }

?>
```

Comment: Output is:- Array ( [0] => cid ) @Bhavin Thummar

Comment: Do you want to get just value?

Comment: please check my updated answer where I have changed the spanlist variable from array to string.

Comment: If <span class="cid">45</span>  Then i want only 45 in php variable.

Comment: means do you want to get the content between the span tag which is have cid class?

Comment: I checked updated answer and output is:- cid
@Bhavin Thummar

Comment: Yes, i want content from span in php variable @Bhavin Thummar

Comment: One more thing I want to know about this requirement 
There one $cid variable which is contained one span tag right now. There will be a chance of multiple span tag vales inside it?

Comment: But span content is coming from js file, so span tag is:- <span class="cid"></span>  and there is no multiple span tag  @Bhavin Thummar

Comment: @user11093829 when you will add the content value "45" inside the span tab?

Comment: @user11093829 Can you print the whole code with js file? so we can understand your full code.

Comment: No you can not print php code in .js file. But you can print js code in php file

Answer (score 0):

Add an `AJAX` code to pass it to PHP

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'your_php_file.php',
    method: 'POST',
    data: {cid: $('.cid')[0].innerText},
    success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
    }
})
```

And in your `PHP` file.
You can just use `strip_tags`

```
 echo strip_tags($_POST['cid']);
```

Comment: But span content is coming from js file, so my span is like this:-  <span class="cid"></span>    @Bluetree

Comment: @user11093829 Then it is not possible to get the value of the span. You need to use `AJAX` to pass it in `PHP`.

Comment: @user11093829 I updated my code. You need to add `AJAX` and create a `PHP` file that will handle the request.

Comment: @user11093829 I updated my answer. You need to access the variable using `$_POST`